# Problema com ASP.net e servidor de hospedagem GoDaddy

Tags: asp.net

Estou enfrentando um problema bastante chato faz alguns dias em que até o momento não consegui uma solução.
Contratei uma hospedagem da GoDaddy (hospedagem Windows Deluxe com plesk) para subir meus projetos em ASP.net.
Tinha desenvolvido um projeto que até então testava na web através da hospagem Umbler e mesmo rodava normalmente. Após algumas pesquisas e a vontade de ir para um servidor mais robusto e confiável, optei por ir para a GoDaddy.
Resolvi então subir o projeto para a GoDaddy e para a minha supresa, ocorreu um erro. Verifiquei o painel da GoDaddy e vi que o framework que esta ativo é o 4.6.2, meu projeto foi feito no 4.5.2.
Resolvi então fazer um teste. Fiz um novo projeto seguindo esses passos no Visual Studio Community 2017:

Arquivo -> Novo -> Projeto -> Aplicativo Web ASP.NET (.NET Framework 4.6.2).

No modelo do ASP.NET 4.6.2 selecione a opção vazio e as pastas de referência não selecionei nenhuma.
Ao abrir esse projeto, adicionei uma página Default.aspx com um Hello World. Compilei o projeto, publiquei via FTP para o servidor da GoDaddy na opção release. Acessei o link do site e ele apresentou o seguinte erro:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Security Exception
>
> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not
>   allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the
>   required permission please contact your system administrator or change
>   the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SecurityException: Request failed.]
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(RuntimeAssembly
>   asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand,
>   IPermission permThatFailed) +96
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Object
>   assemblyOrString, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand,
>   IPermission permThatFailed) +80
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(PermissionSet
>   grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, Object assemblyOrString,
>   SecurityAction action, Boolean throwException) +288
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(CompressedStack
>   cs, PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet
>   demands, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, RuntimeAssembly asm,
>   SecurityAction action) +70
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName) +70    System.RuntimeType.GetType(String
>   typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean
>   reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +40
>   System.Type.GetType(String typeName) +30
>   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerInfo.get_IsCodeDomProviderTypeValid()
>   +12    System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.GetRecompilationHash(CompilationSection
>   ps) +2045
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.get_RecompilationHash()
>   +107    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDateInternal(Int64
>   cachedHash) +458
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate(Int64
>   cachedHash) +51
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +135
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1590.0

Meu web.config esta da seguinte forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Para obter mais informações sobre como configurar seu aplicativo ASP.NET, visite
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Pesquisei na internet e vi que poderia ser questão do trust. Foi então que verifiquei o painel da GoDaddy e setei a opção do CAS para full. Salvei as configurações. Fui no meu web.config e adicionei a seguinte linha:

```
<securityPolicy>
     <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal" />
</securityPolicy>
```

Testei novamente a aplicação e apresentou um erro diferente:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact
>   your system administrator
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: This program
>   is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system
>   administrator
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): This program is blocked by group policy.
>   For more information, contact your system administrator]
>
> [ExternalException (0x80004005): Cannot execute a program. The command
>   being executed was
>   "G:\PleskVhosts\restless-game.com\bumoosool\bin\roslyn\csc.exe"
>   /shared /keepalive:"10" /noconfig  /fullpaths
>   @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\da84e459\c0d920d4\yfdxpfx3.cmdline".]
>   System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCaptureUnimpersonated(SafeUserTokenHandle
>   userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection
>   tempFiles, String& outputName, String& errorName, String trueCmdLine)
>   +6980828    System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCapture(SafeUserTokenHandle
>   userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection
>   tempFiles, String& outputName, String& errorName, String trueCmdLine)
>   +115    System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCapture(IntPtr userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection
>   tempFiles, String& outputName, String& errorName) +81
>   Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.Compile(CompilerParameters
>   options, String compilerFullPath, String arguments, String&
>   outputFile, Int32& nativeReturnValue) +270
>   Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] fileNames) +680
>   Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] fileNames) +186
>   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] fileNames) +24
>   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() +950
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +10099549
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath) +10098677
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate) +294
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +103
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound) +165
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp) +43
>   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context,
>   String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +31 
>   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context,
>   String requestType, String virtualPath, String path) +37
>   System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +339    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1590.0

Voltei ao painel da GoDaddy e confirmei que a trust estava em Full conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: Configurações do ASP.net na GoDaddy]

Subi esse projeto vazio no Drive caso alguém precise para entender o que eu estou passando.

**Download:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_SDbVzeLqJYQWpETDM1LVNmbVk/view?usp=sharing

Se necessário, posso fornecer o usuário FTP que acessa somente esse local onde estão os arquivos publicados na GoDaddy.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda :)

Comment: Tive o mesmo problema na LocaWeb. A politica para execução das aplicações da maioria dos Hosts aqui no BR é configurada para Médio. No meu caso, como a LocaWeb não vai mudar esta política, foi trocar de Host. Rede Host é a que tem o melhor custo benefício.

Answer (score 1):

Tive a ajuda de um outro usuário em outro local onde ele me orientou para colocar no **web.config** assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Para obter mais informações sobre como configurar seu aplicativo ASP.NET, visite
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <trust level="Full"/>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Na solução, entrar na opção de editar o pacote **NuGet** e desinstalar **DotNetCompilerPlatform**. Após fazer isso, consegui subir o site normalmente e efetuar a conexão com um BD MySQL.